# Hypertexting by pasting a link using a toolbar

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have to say I started Javascript and React this week so I am not really familiar with it yet or with anything in the front end.

I have a link button in side a toolbar. I want to be able to click it, opening a text box where I can write a link, and then the text is hypertexted with it. Just want to say that any tip is appreciated.

Something like the following pictures.

[image: Toolbar with link button marked in red]
[image: After clicked the link button]

I have coded the toolbar already and am using the slate-react module for the Editor (the text editor used). I am trying to follow what was done in a GitHub example, which is not exactly the same.

So, in essence, it is a link component inside a toolbar, which is inside a "Tooltip" component (that contains the horizontal toolbar plus another vertical bar), which is inside the editor.

**My question is**: How do I use react and slate editor to tie the Links together in the toolbar? Does the Link component need a state and onChange function? How can I include the Link component in the toolbar (button group), alongside the other buttons within "const Marks"?

I get that these questions might be basic but I am a beginner and would appreciate explanation.

My created Link component can wrap and unwrap link. When clicked,

```
onClickLink = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const { value } = this.state
  const hasLinks = this.hasLinks()
  const change = value.change()

  if (hasLinks) {
    change.call(this.unwrapLink)
  } 

  else 
  {
    const href = window.prompt('Enter the URL of the link:')
    change.call(this.wrapLink, href)
  } 

  this.onChange(change)
}
```

The wrap, unwrap and hasLinks boolean

```
class Links extends React.Component {
onChange = ({ value }) => {
      this.setState({ value })
}
wrapLink(change, href) {
change.wrapInline({
  type: 'link',
  data: { href },
})

change.moveToEnd() }

unwrapLink(change) {
change.unwrapInline('link') }

hasLinks = () => {
  const { value } = this.state
  return value.inlines.some(inline => inline.type == 'link')
}
```

To render it in the editor.

```
const renderNode = ({ children, node, attributes }) => {
  switch (node.type) {
     case 'link': {
        const { data } = node
        const href = data.get('href')
        return (
          <a {...attributes} href={href}>
            {children}
          </a>
        )
      }
```

The "Tooltip" component, holding MarkSelect (the horizontal toolbar like the one in the picures) and another vertical bar called NodeSelector.

```
    function Tooltip({ onChange, value }: Props) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SelectionPlacement
        value={value}
        render={({ placement: { left, top, isActive } }) => (
          <div
            id=...
              {
                isActive,
              },
            )}
            style={{ left, top }}
          >
            <NodeSelector onChange={onChange} value={value} />
            <MarkSelector onChange={onChange} value={value} />
          </div>
        )}
      />
```

The MarkSelector and other Marks (buttons) in the button group.

```
const MarkSelector = function MarkSelector({ onChange, value }: Props) {
  return (
    <ButtonGroup className=...>
      {Marks.map(({ tooltip, text, type }) => {
        const isActive = value.activeMarks.some(mark => mark.type === type);
        return (
          <Tooltip key={type} title={tooltip}>
            <Button
              className={classNames({ 'secondary-color': isActive })}
              onMouseDown={event => {
                event.preventDefault();

                const change = value.change().toggleMark(type);
                onChange(change);
              }}
              size=...
              style=...
              }}
            >
              {text}
            </Button>
          </Tooltip>
        );
      })}
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
};

const Marks = [
  {
    type: BOLD,
    text: <strong>B</strong>,
    tooltip: (
      <strong>
        Bold
        <div className=...</div>
      </strong>
    ),
  },
  {
    type: ITALIC,
    text:...
```

The editor with the tooltip.

```
render() {
const { onChangeHandler, onKeyDown, value, readOnly } = this.props;
return (
  <div
    className=...
    id=...
    style=..
  >
    {!readOnly && (
      <EditorTooltip value={value} onChange={onChangeHandler} />
    )}

    <SlateEditor
      ref=...
      className=...
      placeholder=...
      value={value}
      plugins={plugins}
      onChange={onChangeHandler}
      onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
      renderNode={renderNode}
      renderMark={renderMark}
      readOnly={readOnly}
    />
    {!readOnly && <ClickablePadding onClick={this.focusAtEnd} grow />}
  </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a recommended way to manipulate DOM directly in data-driven frontend frameworks, but you could always get the HTML element of the link, and set its innerHTML (which is the hypertext) according to internal states. This is hacky but it might works.